# My route to delete is redirecting me to show.blade instead of destroying the data with corresponding id

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I am trying to delete a particular data with corresponding id but it redirects me to the Show page although the route is directing it to destroy.

My index.blade

```
<td><form class="action"><button type="submit" formaction="{{route('products.show',$product->id)}}">Show</button></form></td>

<td><form class="action"><button type="submit"  formaction="{{route('products.edit',$product->id)}}">Edit</button></form></td>

<td><form class="delete" action="{{ route('products.destroy',$product->id) }}">
  @csrf
  @method('DELETE')
  <button>Delete</button>
  </form></td>
```

My Controller for destroy

```
public function destroy(Product $product)
    {
        $product->delete();
        return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('success','Data deleted successfully!!!');
    }
```

My Controller for show

```
public function show(Product $product)
    {
        return view('products.show',compact('product'));
    }
```

My controller for index

`````
    {
        $products = Product::latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('products.index',compact('products'));
    }````

Route
````Route::resource('/products',ProductController::class);````


I tried using <a> link tag also but it does the same and also the data gets deleted perfectly fine when I delete it from database manually.
`````

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? The code you've shared does not contain an redirects

Comment: $product->delete();
        return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('success','Data deleted successfully!!!'); I used this too but it doesnt work

Comment: Basically, its not deleting the corressponding id from the database after I press the delete button instead it takes me to the show.blade. I dont know why

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: There u go !!!!

Comment: I did add the route and index controller now @JSTECH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your delete button form does not have a button `type="submit"` also it doesn't have  `method="post"` try below code.

```
<form class="delete" action="{{ route('products.destroy',$product->id) }}" 
method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

I hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
index.blade 
<form class="delete" action="{{ route('products.destroy',$product->id) }}" 
method="POST">
   @csrf
   @method('DELETE')
   <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>

controller

public function destroy(string $id)
{
    $product= Product::findOrFail($id);
    $product->delete();
    return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('success','Data 
    deleted successfully!!!');
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it